# Anyone know of a completely fanless & portless edge computer?

Tags: linux, freebsd

Looking for a rugged edge computer with absolutely zero ports, including no power port and solid state only (SSDs, etc).  For example, it could be magnetically charged with a battery in the case & use exclusively wi-fi networking.  Anything like that exist?  Bonus points for one that includes multiple compute nodes inside, like 2, 3, 5, 9+ computers connected via an internal rack.

Comment: You may be looking at an apple watch.